# Reset username in APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

If you have custom authentication within APEX you can make a form on your own custom user table.

My problem is that when the logged in user changes his own username APEX goes total wookiee.

So I tried to make a trigger which would (at least I hoped) reset the user name variable:

***Trigger code*** *Note: this trigger is made on a view not on a table*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_change_student
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON view_student
BEGIN
    UPDATE user SET email = :new.email, password = :new.password WHERE email = LOWER(:old.email);
    UPDATE student SET fk_study = :new.fk_study, name = :new.name, bsn = :new.bsn WHERE pk_huurder = :new.pk_huurder;
    APEX_UTIL.SET_USERNAME(
        p_userid     => APEX_UTIL.GET_USER_ID(:old.email),
        P_username   => :new.email);
    -- :APP_USER := :new.email;
    -- apex_authentication.send_login_username_cookie (p_username => lower(:new.email) );
    -- apex_application.g_user := :new.email;
END;
```

But when I change the username the :APP_USER still contains the old username. So how can I set :APP_USER?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to change it from inside a trigger, you need to do it from an apex session. Try to make a **Onload** process inside your apex page and use `wwv_flow.g_user:=new_email` to change the login user.